# $L^1$ and a.s. convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

it seems almost impossible to infer results about almost sure convergence from results about $L^1$ convergence.

I have the following problem:

> Let $X$ be a $L^2$ random variable ($\int_\Omega X^2 d\mathbb{P} < \infty$). Let further $Z_k = \vert X \vert \mathbb{1}_{\{X^2 \geq 2^k\}}$ (where $\mathbb{1}$ shall denote the indicator function). I want to show that $2^{k/2} Z_k \to 0$ almost surely.

What I was able to show is that

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k \mathbb{P}(X^2 \geq 2^k) \leq \mathbb{E}(X^2) < \infty$ and also that $2^{k/2} \Vert Z_k \Vert_1 \to 0$.

My initial plan was to conclude from the latter one, that somehow also $2^{k/2} Z_k \to 0$ almost surely, but as I mentioned initially, this doesn't work.

Now I came up with the idea to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma: Let $\varepsilon > 0$, then

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(2^{k/2} Z_k > \varepsilon)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(2^{k/2} \vert X \vert \mathbb{1}_{\{X^2 \geq 2^k\})}> \varepsilon) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert^2 \geq 2^k) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k \mathbb{P}(X^2 \geq 2^k) < \infty$,

where the first inequality comes from the fact, that $Z_k = 0$ for $\vert X \vert^2 < 2^k$. This would then proof the statement in view of the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Either, this works and I was on the wrong path with the $L^1$ convergence. Or there is an error in my reasoning and I'm still deadlost. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, there’s usually no clear-cut path from $L^1$ convergence to as convergence. Your second reasoning seems to work, but I think it’s needlessly complicated. Indeed, $(Z_k(\omega))_k$ is stationary to zero if $|X|(\omega) < \infty$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$. As $X$ is $L^2$, this condition occurs for almost every $\omega$.

Comment: We have pointwise that $Z_k = 0$ for $k$ large since $1_{\{X^2 \geq 2^k\}} = 0$ for $k$ large. Hence $Z_k \to 0$ a.s..

Answer (score 1):

We have $\omega$-wise $$
2^{k/2} Z_k \not\to 0 \iff Z_k\not=0\quad \forall k\in\Bbb N \iff X^2 \ge 2^k \quad\forall k\in\Bbb N \iff X^2 = +\infty
$$

and so:
$$
\Bbb P(2^{k/2}Z_k \not\to 0) =  \Bbb P( X^2 = +\infty) = 0$$ hence $\Bbb P(2^{k/2}Z_k \to 0) = 1$ so a.s.